# Split column label by number of letters/characters in R

Tags: regex, r, split, multiple-columns

I have a large dataset where all column headers are individual IDS, each 8 characters in length. I would like to split those individual IDs into 2 rows, where the first row of IDs contains the first 7 characters, and the second row contains just the last character.

Current dataset:

```
ID1:    Indiv01A    Indiv01B    Indiv02A    Indiv02B    Speci03A    Speci03B
```

Intended dataset:

```
ID1:    Indiv01 Indiv01 Indiv02 Indiv02 Speci03 Speci03  
ID2:    A   B   A   B   A   B
```

I've looked through other posts on splitting data, but they all seem to have a unique way to separate the column name (ie: there's a comma separating the 2 components, or a period).

This is the code I'm thinking would work best, but I just can't figure out how to code for "7 characters" as the split point, rather than a comma:

`sapply(strsplit(as.character(d$ID), ",")`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a regular expression for a solution with `strsplit`. It splits the string between the 7th and the 8th character:

```
ID1 <- c("Indiv01A", "Indiv01B", "Indiv02A", "Indiv02B", "Speci03A", "Speci03B")

res <- strsplit(ID1, "(?<=.{7})", perl = TRUE)

# [[1]]
# [1] "Indiv01" "A"      
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Indiv01" "B"      
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "Indiv02" "A"      
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "Indiv02" "B"      
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "Speci03" "A"      
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] "Speci03" "B"
```

Now, you can use `rbind` to create two columns:

```
do.call(rbind, res)
#      [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] "Indiv01" "A" 
# [2,] "Indiv01" "B" 
# [3,] "Indiv02" "A" 
# [4,] "Indiv02" "B" 
# [5,] "Speci03" "A" 
# [6,] "Speci03" "B"
```

---

Explanation of the regex pattern:

```
(?<=.{7})
```

The `(?<=)` is a (positive) lookbehind. It matches any position that is preceded by the specified pattern. Here, the pattern is `.{7}`. The dot (`.`) matches any character. `{7}` means *7 times*. Hence, the regex matches the position that is preceded by exactly 7 characters.

Comment: +1 Much more elegant than my offering. Would you mind explaining your pattern?

Comment: @jbaums I added an explanation.

Comment: This is a great explanation and easy to understand! My only difficulty is that I'm still getting stuck trying to apply it to just my column headers, or the first row in the data.frame. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: @user2296922 You can get the column names with `colnames(dat)` and the first row with `dat[1, ]` where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Comment: I'm trying to create 2 rows, since the first row is all column headers. I've gotten the code to work as you've laid it out with the suggestion of colnames; i just can't link the new column headers (2 rows) back to the original data.frame (FK1):     > ID1 <- colnames(FK1)
> ID1
[1] "Year"     "FK1A001A" "FK1A001B" "FK1A002A" "FK1A002B" "FK1A003A"
[7] "FK1A003B" "FK1B006A" "FK1B006B"      > ID1new <- strsplit(ID1, "(?<=.{7})", perl=TRUE)     > do.call(rbind,ID1new)     Then I'm stuck to get ID1new merged with ID1.

Comment: @user2296922 Does this mean, you want *2* column headers? This is not possible in R. Why do you need it?

Comment: I have a second dataframe that I'm trying to merge with the current data set. The second dataframe has all columns labeled with the first 7 character ID (ex: Indiv01). I'm looking for a way to separate the 8 character column headers (ex: Indiv01A and Indiv01B) in the first dataframe so that I can merge the two dataframes according to the 7-character ID. Trying to merge them so both Indiv01A and Indiv01B can be matched to the information linked to Indiv01.

Comment: @user2296922 You can try `colnames(FK1) <- sapply(res, "[", 1)` to change the column names.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a gsubfn solution:

```
library(gsubfn)

strapplyc(ID1, "(.*)(.)", simplify = cbind)
```

which gives this matrix:

```
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]     
[1,] "Indiv01" "Indiv01" "Indiv02" "Indiv02" "Speci03" "Speci03"
[2,] "A"       "B"       "A"       "B"       "A"       "B"
```

or use `rbind` in place of `cbind` if you want two columns (rather than two rows).

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this package - haven't come across it before!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you could go about this.

**To extract the final character**

First, with `substr`:

```
new.vec <- sapply(old.vec, function(x) substr(x, nchar(x), nchar(x)))
```

or, with `sub`:

```
new.vec <- sub('.*(.)', '\\1', old.vec)
```

where `old.vec` is the vector of strings that you want to split.

For interest, the latter option uses a [regular expression](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html) that translates to: "capture (indicating by surrounding with parentheses) the single character (`.`) that follows zero or more other characters (`.*`), and replace matches with the captured content (`\\1`)". For more info, see `?gsub`, and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

The above options allow for varying string lengths. However, if you do *always* want to split after 7 characters, and the second part of the string always has just a single character, then the following should work:

```
new.vec <- substr(old.vec, 8, 8)
```

---

(Edited to include method for extracting the first part of the string.)

**To extract all *but* the final character**

The process is similar.

```
new.vec <- sapply(old.vec, function(x) substr(x, 1, nchar(x) - 1))

new.vec <- sub('(.*).', '\\1', old.vec)

new.vec <- substr(old.vec, 1, 7)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I've tried both option 1 and 3, and I'm having difficulty because of trying to denote which row to change. The first row in the dataset ("Year") contains the individual IDs. I've tried the following code, with the output following.    > FK1split <- sapply(FK1$"Year", function(x) substr(x, nchar(7),nchar(1)))
> FK1split
 [1] "1" "1" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2"
> FK1split <- substr(FK1$Year, 8, 8)
> FK1split
 [1] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""     Any thoughts on how to easily indicate which row of the data.frame should be split?

Comment: Don't change `x` to `7` and `1` in the first version - your change just extracts the first character of each element of `FK1$Year`. Also, understand that `substr(FK1$Year, 8, 8)` is saying to extract the 8th to 8th (i.e., just the 8th) character of each element of `FK1$Year`. It looks like `FK1$Year` probably doesn't have 8 characters. Adjust `8` and `8` accordingly (they indicate where to start and end extraction). By the way, enclose code in backticks (usually on the tilde `~` key) to format code in comments.